# Down to Zero II

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This is the question:

> You are given Q queries. Each query consists of a single number N . You can perform any of the  operations on  in each move:
>
> 1. If we take 2 integers a and b where N=a*b (a ,b cannot be equal to 1), then we can change N=max(a,b)
> 2. Decrease the value of N by 1 .
>
> Determine the minimum number of moves required to reduce the value of  to .
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains the integer Q.
> The next Q lines each contain an integer,N .
>
> Output Format
>
> Output Q lines. Each line containing the minimum number of moves required > to reduce the value of N to 0.

I have written the following code. This code is giving some wrong answers and also giving time limit exceed error . Can you tell what are the the mistakes present in my code ? where or what I am doing wrong here?

My code:

```
public static int downToZero(int n) {
// Write your code here
    int count1=0;
    int prev_i=0;
    int prev_j=0;
    int next1=0;
    int next2=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    if (n==0){
        return 0;
    }

    while(n!=0){
        if(n==1){
            count1++;
            break;
        }
        next1=n-1;
        outerloop:
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
                if (i*j==n){
                    if (prev_i ==j && prev_j==i){
                        break outerloop;
                    }
                    if (i !=j){
                        prev_i=i;
                        prev_j=j;
                    }
                    int max=Math.max(i,j);
                    if (max<next2){
                        next2=max;
                    }
                       
                }
                
            }
        }
        n=Math.min(next1,next2);
        count1++;
    }
    return count1;
}
```

This is part is coded for us:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int q = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        for (int qItr = 0; qItr < q; qItr++) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

            int result = Result.downToZero(n);

            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Ex: it is not working for number 7176 ....

Comment: What is upper limit for N?

Comment: Have you tried debugging a failing case? What where your findings?

Comment: I tried it but I wasn't able to find anything.....

Comment: Some random thoughts - since you have multiple paths to the solution, a recursive approach is perhaps needed. Case 1 asks whether there is one or more prime factorizations, so you will need a helper function to calculate the prime factors of a given number.

Comment: I don't see N constraints in the question. In any case, you perform **greedy** choice, that does not lead to the globally best solution in general case. You need to make search (BFS) over tree of all possible cases. If N cannot be not too much, you can remember partial solutions (memoize)

Comment: Can you provide few sample input and output.

Comment: Constraints:
1<=Q<=10^3
0<=N<=10^6

Comment: OK, N is pretty small. Make table[1000000] to save solved cases.

Comment: Sample Input - 2 3 4 Sample Output - 3 3

Comment: Input:  1 7176 , output:  7

Comment: for some reason I am not able to save the edit so I have given some samples here :)

Comment: OP, do you have other inputs and expected results? I think I have a good idea of solving this without brute-forcing, but I need some more input to test my approach.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/down-to-zero-ii/problem this is it :)

Comment: yeah I am doing that question only :D  Should I post more input and output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explore all solution tree and find globally optimal solution, we must choose the best result both **from  all possible divisor pairs** and from `solution(n-1)`

My weird translation to Java [(ideone)](https://ideone.com/MRAmNq) uses bottom-up dynamic programming to make execution faster.

We calculate solutions for values `i` from `1` to `n`, they are written into `table[i]`.

At first we set result into `1 + best result for previous value (table[i-1])`.

Then we factor `N` into **all pairs** of divisors and check whether using already calculated result for larger divisor `table[d]` gives better result.

Finally we write result into the table.

Note that we can calculate `table` once and use it for all `Q` queries.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static int makezeroDP(int n){
       int[] table = new int[n+1];
       table[1] = 1; table[2] = 2; table[3] = 3;
       int res;
       for (int i = 4; i <= n; i++) {
          res = 1 + table[i-1];
          int a = 2;
          while (a * a <= i) {
             if (i % a == 0)
                res = Math.min(res, 1 + table[i / a]);
             a += 1;
          }
          table[i] = res;
       }
       return table[n];
    }
     
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    { 
        int n = 145;//999999;
        System.out.println(makezeroDP(n));
    }
}
```

---

Old part

Simple implementation (sorry, in Python) gives answer `7` for `7176`

```
def makezero(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n
    result = 1 + makezero(n - 1)
    t = 2
    while t * t <= n:
        if n % t == 0:
            result = min(result, 1 + makezero(n // t))
        t += 1
    return result
```

In Python it's needed to set recursion limit or change algorithm. Now use memoization, as I wrote in comments).

```
t = [-i for i in range(1000001)]
def makezeroMemo(n):
    if t[n] > 0:
        return t[n]
    if t[n-1] < 0:
        res = 1 + makezeroMemo(n-1)
    else:
        res = 1 + t[n-1]
    a = 2
    while a * a <= n:
        if n % a == 0:
            res = min(res, 1 + makezeroMemo(n // a))
        a += 1
    t[n] = res
    return res
```

Bottom-up table dynamic programming. No recursion.

```
def makezeroDP(n):
    table = [0,1,2,3] + [0]*(n-3)
    for i in range(4, n+1):
        res = 1 + table[i-1]
        a = 2
        while a * a <= i:
            if i % a == 0:
                res = min(res, 1 + table[i // a])
            a += 1
        table[i] = res
    return table[n]
```

Comment: According to @user3386109, answer for 145 is 145, 144, 16, 4, 2, 1, taking 6 steps to reach 0. Your implementation gives 30. Like me, you have assumed that we need to use 2nd rule when we can't factor out, so it turns out that it isn't ideal. I don't know how to approach the problem without brute force and memoisation. I guess we need to take min between makeZero(n) and makeZero(n - 1) when n is odd. I don't know if there is a case where you have an even number and makeZero(n - 1) would yield better results ... Fascinating problem, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Silviu Burcea Yes, you are right - I definitely have some error in memoization implementation, because initial recursion and dynamic programming approaches give 6

Comment: Yea, so I've found this. Best 45 chain I've found on paper is 45, 9, 3, 2, 1(5 chain).  Best chain for 46 I've found on paper is 46, 23, 22, 11, 10, 5, 4, 2, 1 (9 chain).  However, you can go 46, 45, 9, 3, 2, 1(6 chain), which is obviously better.

Comment: @Silviu Burce I found and corrected mistake in memoization (but lost faster way in some cases :( )

Answer (score 2):

We can construct the directed acyclic graph quickly with a sieve and
then compute shortest paths. No trial division needed.

Time and space usage is Θ(N log N).

```
n_max = 1000000
successors = [[n - 1] for n in range(n_max + 1)]
for a in range(2, n_max + 1):
    for b in range(a, n_max // a + 1):
        successors[a * b].append(b)
table = [0]
for n in range(1, n_max + 1):
    table.append(min(table[s] for s in successors[n]) + 1)
print(table[7176])
```

Results:

```
7
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

The algorithm uses Greedy approach and doesn't return optimal results, it just simplifies OP's approach. For 7176 given as example, below algorithm returns 10, I can see a shorter chain of 7176 -> 104 -> 52 -> 13 -> 12 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 with 8 steps, and expected answer is 7.

---

Let's review your problem in simple terms.

> If we take 2 integers a and b where N=a*b (a ,b cannot be equal to 1), then we can change N=max(a,b)
> and

> Determine the minimum number of moves required to reduce the value of to .

You're looking for 2 factors of `N`, `a` and `b` and, if you want the minimum number of moves, this means that your maximum at each step should be minimum. We know for a fact that this minimum is reached when factors are closest to `N`. Let me give you an example:

36 = 1 * 36 = 2 * 18 = 3 * 12 = 4 * 9 = 6 * 6

We know that `sqrt(36) = 6` and you can see that the minimum of 2 factors you can get at this step is max(6, 6) = 6. Sure, 36 is 6 squared, let me take a number without special properties, 96, with its square root rounded down to nearest integer 9.

96 = 2 * 48 = 3 * 32 = 4 * 24 = 6 * 16 = 8 * 12

You can see that your minimum value for `max(a, b)` is `max(8, 12) = 12`, which is, again, attained when factors are closest to square root.

Now let's look at the code:

```
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
  for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
    if (i*j==n){
```

You can do this in one loop, knowing that `n / i` returns an integer, therefore you need to check if `i * (n / i) == n`. With the previous observation, we need to start at the square root, and go down, until we get to 1. If we got `i` and `n / i` as factors, we know that this pair is also the minimum you can get at this step. If no factors are found and you reach 1, which obviously is a factor of `n`, you have a prime number and you need to use the second instruction:

> Decrease the value of N by 1 .

Note that if you go from `sqrt(n)` down to 1, looking for factors, if you find one, `max(i, n / i)` will be `n / i`.

Additionally, if n = 1, you take 1 step. If n = 2, you take 2 steps (2 -> 1). If n = 3, you take 3 steps (3 -> 2 -> 1). Therefore if n is 1, 2 or 3, you take `n` steps to go to 0. OK, less talking, more coding:

```
static int downToZero(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3) return n;
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = sqrt; i > 1; i--) {
        if (n / i * i == n) {
            return 1 + downToZero(n / i);
        }
    }
    return 1 + downToZero(n - 1);
}
```

Notice that I'm stopping when `i` equals 2, I know that if I reach 1, it's a prime number and I need to go a step forward and look at `n - 1`.

However, I have tried to see the steps your algorithm and mine takes, so I've added a print statement each time n changes, and we both have the same succession: 7176, 92, 23, 22, 11, 10, 5, 4, 2, 1, which returns 10. Isn't that correct?

Comment: I also got the ans 10 but the ans is 7

Comment: The actual answer is 7176, 552, 24, 12, 4, 2, 1. Which demonstrates that choosing the factor closest to the square root is not always optimal. And the answer to 145 is 145, 144, 16, 4, 2, 1. Which demonstrates that using **decrease-N-by-1** only when the number cannot be factored is also not optimal.

Comment: @user3386109 I've also found 7176, 312, 24, 8, 4, 2, 1. I have missunderstood the 2nd rule, I've thought that *decrease-N-by-1* is only used when you can factor (prime).

Comment: Yes, I should have said, "One of the answers with 7 steps is ...". There are actually 8 answers with 7 steps for 7176.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution which is working for all the test cases -

```
static final int LIMIT = 1_000_000; 
static int[] solutions = buildSolutions();

public static int downToZero(int n) {
    // Write your code here
    return solutions[n];
}
static int[] buildSolutions() {
    int[] solutions = new int[LIMIT + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < solutions.length; i++) {
        solutions[i] = solutions[i - 1] + 1;

        for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                solutions[i] = Math.min(solutions[i], solutions[i / j] + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return solutions;
}
}
```

Comment: It is essentially the same code  that I made